# Using objectify to get items with a different namespace prefix

Tags: python, xml, lxml, objectify

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
</entry>
```

I would like to use lxml.objectify to access both 'Hello World!' and 'USA'.  How can it be done?  I am not concerned with efficiency, just parsimony.  I've tried everything I can think of to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this setup:

```
import lxml.objectify as objectify
import io

content='''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dd="http://example.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<entry>
    <content type="html">Hello World!</content>
    <dd:country_code>USA</dd:country_code>
</entry>
</feed>'''

doc=objectify.parse(io.BytesIO(content))
tree=doc.getroot()
```

The short and quick way:

```
print(list(tree.entry.iterchildren()))
# ['Hello World!', 'USA']
```

Or the more specific way:

```
print(tree.entry["content"])
# Hello World!
```

to handle namespaces:

```
print(tree.entry["{http://example.com/ns/1.0}country_code"])
# USA
```

This method of accessing namespaces is [documented here](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#namespace-handling).